# How to use loop cut on an irregular shaped mesh

Tags: edit-mode

I am modelling a 'shed' which has a sloping flat roof.
I want to add 'timber panels' around the top of the walls but want the bottom edge of those panels to be horizontal.
I tried loop cuts and moved the cut to near the top of the walls however as I move the cut towards the top the loop cut 'follows' the top of the wall instead of remaining horizontal.
Please advise how I can 'model' this.
Here is the image in blender - note the roof is sloping and so the look cut at the top is also 'sloping' which I don't want.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add an horizontal edge loop you can either cut with the *Knife* tool (<kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>A</kbd> to cut orthogonally, <kbd>C</kbd> to cut through) or loop cut with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> then slide with <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and press <kbd>E</kbd> to align with the edge, <kbd>F</kbd> to switch from an edge to another.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks heaps. I also learned to use Ctrl R and G G (I used to drag with the mouse).